# Split in two pieces a multi-word sentence in R

Tags: r, split

I need to split/wrap programmatically in **two rows** some multi-word sentences, say "This is an example of a multi-word sentence". How to replace the white space closest to the middle of the sentence with a `"\n"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be able to play around with something using `strwrap`.

Here's a very basic implementation:

```
sentSplit <- function(string, tolerance = 1.05, collapse = "\n") {
  paste(strwrap(string, width = nchar(string)/2 * tolerance), collapse = collapse)
}

sent <- "This is an example of a multi-word sentence"
sentSplit(sent)
# [1] "This is an example of\na multi-word sentence"

cat(sentSplit(sent))
# This is an example of
# a multi-word sentence
```

The "tolerance" argument is basically because in some cases, it might split the string into 3 pieces, at which point, you can increase the tolerance to have at most two splits.

Comment: Nice, I was just going to post `str <- "This is an example of a multi-word sentence"; 
Res <- paste(substring(str, c(1, nchar(str)/2 + 1), c(nchar(str)/2 + 1, nchar(str))), collapse = "\n");
cat(Res)`, but I guess it's almost the same as yours, just worse :)

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution using `strwrap()`:

```
x <- "This is an example of a multi-word sentence"

wrapInTwo <- function(x, fraction = 0.6) strwrap(x, width = fraction * nchar(x))

wrapInTwo(x)

[1] "This is an example of a" "multi-word sentence"
```